# Generic Class object reference declaration when using getSuperclass() method

Tags: java, generics

Suppose there are two classes: 
**Circle** extends **Shape**

The **Class** object of **Circle** can be accessed using:
`Class<Circle> circleClass = Circle.class;`

However, there is a compile error when getting the **Class** object of **Shape** in this way:
`Class<Shape> shapeClass = circleClass.getSuperclass();`

I do not understand why the compiler does not allow this declaration. Since Java only allows each class to have only one base class and the compiler knows what that base class (ie, **Shape**) is at compile time.

Comment: The return type of `getSuperClass` is `Class<? super T>`, which is not assignable to a `Class<Shape>`.